# Printing Problems with WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[image]I have Googled this problem and while there are some hints at fixes, most are theme specific.  I did find a link to create a print.css and it works somewhat but the menu navigation still prints over the content in the web page.  I only want the content of the page to print...no header, footer, sidebar, or navigation menu.  The style page I created via direction of the link is below.  I also added the link to the header.php as directed.  It seems the print.css works for everything but the navigation menu.  There is a custom style sheet named nations-styles.css referred to in the header.php and located at /wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/css.  I'm thinking there might be additional navigation problems that need to be address with that style sheet.  I am new to CSS, so I'm not sure how to make this work so they navigation doesn't show up in the printing of the page.  I've tried #header, .nav-box {display:none} and that doesn't seem to work either.

All help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

print.css below

```
@media print {
body {background:white; 
     font-size:10pt; 
     margin:0 }
#sidebar { display:none }
#header { display:none}
#header, .nav-box {display:none}
#nav {display:none}
#content{ margin-left:0; 
     float:none; 
     width:auto }
.demo .red { color:black; 
     font-weight:bold }
#content a { font-weight:bold; 
     color:#000066; 
     text-decoration:underline }
#content{ margin-left:0; 
     float:none; 
     width:auto }
#footer, .ad { display:none }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { page-break-after:avoid; 
     page-break-inside:avoid }
h3 { margin-left:10px; 
     margin-bottom:0px; 
     padding-bottom:0px }
blockquote, table, pre { page-break-inside:avoid }
ul, ol, dl  { page-break-before:avoid }
img.centered { display: block; 
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto; }
img.right { padding: 4px; 
     margin: 0 0 2px 7px; 
     display: inline; }
img.left { padding: 4px; 
     margin: 0 7px 2px 0; 
     display: inline; }
.right { float: right; }
.left { float: left }
img { page-break-inside:avoid; 
     page-break-after:avoid; }
}
```

header.php below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<title><?php
    /* Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed. */
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'smartbusiness' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
?></title>

<?php
    global $shortname;
    $favicon = get_option($shortname.'_favicon');
    if ($favicon) {
?>
<!-- ~~~~~~ FAVICON ~~~~~~ -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $favicon; ?>" />
<?php } ?>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, <?php if (get_option($shortname."_zoom_feature") == 'No') { echo 'initial-scale=1.0'; } else { echo 'user-scalable=yes'; } ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<?php
    $theme_color_skin = strtolower(get_option($shortname."_theme_color_skin"));
?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/<?php echo $theme_color_skin; ?>/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->   

<!--Added to work with minify - removed from functions.php
<link id="stylesheet_custom_style-css" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/functions/custom-css-main.php" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link id="stylesheet_custom_style-css" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/css/nations-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/print.css" />

</head>
<body <?php body_class('custom-background'); ?>>
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="w1">
            <div class="w2">
                <!-- header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <!-- section -->
                    <div class="section">
                        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php $custom_logo = get_option($shortname.'_logo'); echo $custom_logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a></h1>
                        <div class="contact-box">
                            <?php if (get_option($shortname."_phone_number")) { ?><strong class="phone"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_phone_number"); ?></strong><?php } ?>
                            <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links") == 'true') { ?>

                            <!-- social -->
                            <ul class="social">
                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_twitter")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_twitter"); ?>" class="twitter tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_twitter_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_twitter_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_facebook")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_facebook"); ?>" class="facebook tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_facebook_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_facebook_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_pinterest")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_pinterest"); ?>" class="pinterest tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_pinterest_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_pinterest_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_dribbble")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_dribbble"); ?>" class="dribbble tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_dribbble_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_dribbble_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_vimeo")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_vimeo"); ?>" class="vimeo tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_vimeo_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_vimeo_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_googleplus")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_googleplus"); ?>" class="google tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_googleplus_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_googleplus_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (get_option($shortname."_social_links_rss")) { ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_rss"); ?>" class="rss tool_tip" title="<?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_rss_caption"); ?>"><?php echo get_option($shortname."_social_links_rss_caption"); ?></a></li><?php } ?>

                            </ul>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- nav-box -->
                    <nav class="nav-box">
                        <!-- nav -->
                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                            'menu'              => 'Header Menu',
                            'container'         => '',
                            'container_class'   => '',
                            'container_id'      => '',
                            'menu_class'        => '',
                            'menu_id'           => 'nav',
                            'echo'              => true,
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'fallback_default_menu',
                            'before'            => '',
                            'after'             => '',
                            'link_before'       => '',
                            'link_after'        => '',
                            'depth'             => 0,
                            'walker'            => '',
                            'theme_location'    => 'header_menu'
                            ));

                            //the main menu for iPhone version
                            dropdown_menu( array('dropdown_title' => 'Header Menu', 'indent_string' => ' - ', 'indent_after' => '','container' => '', 'container_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'mobile-meny', 'theme_location'=>'header_menu') );
                        ?>

                    </nav>      

                </header>
```

nations-styles.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Nations Styles */
#main .container h1 { margin-bottom:10px;}
#main .container h2 { margin-bottom:10px;}
#main .container h3 { margin-bottom:10px;}
#main .container h4 { margin-bottom:5px;}
#main .container h5 { margin-bottom:5px;}
#main .container h6 { margin-bottom:5px;}
#main .container p { margin-bottom:15px;}
.space { display: block; width:100%; height:15px;}
strong, b { font-weight: bold;}
ul.ulFloatL { overflow: auto;}
ul.ulFloatL li { float: left; width:49.5%; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;}
ul.ulFloatL li img { max-width:100%; margin:0;}
.overflowH { overflow:hidden;}
.floatL { float:left;}
.iconLogo { margin: 3px 20px 3px 0;}
.grid-cols .col33 { overflow: auto;}
.imgScale { max-width:100%; width:auto;}
#sidebar .widget ~ .widget { margin-top:20px;}
h2 .divider { margin:0 0 10px; padding:0;}
h2 .divider ~ .divider { padding:13px 0 0; margin-bottom: 25px;}
.btn.red, .tp-caption.slide_button a, .comment-form .submit, .tp-caption.slide_button a.btn { background:#C7362D; border: 1px solid #b7261D !important; color:#FFE6E7; border-radius:5px !important; padding:8px 15px 7px; text-transform: uppercase; font:300 14px/16px 'Oswald',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.btn.red:hover, .tp-caption.slide_button a:hover, .comment-form .submit:hover, .tp-caption.slide_button a.btn:hover { background:#b7261D; color:#fff;}
.tp-caption.slide_title { color:#C7362D;}
.comment-form .submit input { opacity:0;}
.fullwidthbanner-container .linklist a { font-size:24px; color:#C7362D; display: block;}
.fullwidthbanner-container .linklist a:hover, .fullwidthbanner-container .linklist a:active, .fullwidthbanner-container .linklist a:focus { color:#333;}

.nav-box #nav .sub-menu { top: 25px;}
.nav-box > ul > li > .has-drop-down-a { background-position: 100% 12px;}
.tp-leftarrow.default, .tp-rightarrow.default { top:50% !important;}

.nocomments { display:none;}
#header { background: #fff url(/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bodyBg-grey.jpg) top center no-repeat;}
#header .section { padding:10px; border: none;}
.nav-box { padding-top:10px;}
.nav-box > ul > li { padding-bottom:11px;}

.social .twitter {background:  transparent url("/wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/css/red/images/twitter-hover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0; opacity:0.7;}
.social .facebook {background: transparent url("/wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/css/red/images/facebook-hover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0; opacity:0.7;}
.social .rss {background: transparent url("/wp-content/themes/smartbusiness/css/red/images/rss-hover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0; opacity:0.7;}
.social .facebook:hover, .social .twitter:hover, .social .rss:hover { opacity:1;}

.fullwidthbanner-container { background-color:#eee;}

#sidebar .current-menu-item a { color:#999;}

div.rss-output { padding:0 0 15px;}
footer .blog-links p, footer .news-contents p { line-height:16px;}
footer .news-contents div ~ div p { margin-top:10px;}
footer .news-contents .news { margin-left:0 !important;}

/* Footer Fix */
#footer, .footer-holder, .footer-frame, footer, footer .add-block { display: block !important; width:100%;}
footer .case { margin:0 auto;}

/* Home Slider */
.fullwidthbanner-container { margin-left:-2000px; float:left;}
.fullwidthbanner-container.loaded {margin-left:0; float:none;}
.fullwidthbanner-container.loaded .fullwidthbanner { max-height:300px;}

/* Theme Styles */
/* logo */
.logo { float:left; background: none; width:136px; height:80px; overflow: visible; text-indent: 0;} 
html {background:#fff;}
.nav-box > ul, .nav-box > ul ul { font:18px/19px "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; } 
.nav-box > ul  ul a { font-size: 14px !important; } 
.nav-box > ul a { color: #FFE6E7 !important; } 
.nav-box > ul  a:hover { color: #ffffff !important; } 
.nav-box > ul ul a { color: #333333 !important; } 
.nav-box > ul ul a:hover { color: #ffffff !important; } 
.nav-box {background:#C7362D; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:Oswald, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {font-family:Oswald, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color:#111111 !important;}
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {color:#111111 !important;}
#footer h1, #footer h2, #footer h3, #footer h4, #footer h5, #footer h6 {color:#b8b8b8 !important;}
#footer h1 a, #footer h2 a, #footer h3 a, #footer h4 a, #footer h5 a, #footer h6 a {color:#b8b8b8 !important;}
#footer h1, #footer h2, #footer h3, #footer h4, #footer h5, #footer h6 {color:#ffffff !important;}
#footer h1 a, #footer h2 a, #footer h3 a, #footer h4 a, #footer h5 a, #footer h6 a {color:#ffffff !important;}
body {font-family:Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
body {font-size:12px;}
body {color:#222222;}
a {color:#C7362D;}
a:hover{color:#001F5B;}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to a page this is happening on? It would be much easier to troubleshoot with a link.

Comment: http://www.nationscompanies.com/about-us/

Comment: I just edited the question to include a screenshot of what the page looks like when you go to print a preview

Comment: Just posted an answer. It seems that you were, in fact, hiding your main menu, but there was another instance of a menu being drawn on your page, most likely through a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a div near the bottom of your page that starts like this:

```
<div class="select-options options-hidden drop-menu drop-dropdown-menu " style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
```

Most likely this is coming in from a menu plugin or your theme.

So in your print stylesheet, add:

```
.drop-holder{display: none !important; visibility:hidden !important;}
```

The "!important" will help force the style to take effect.

In the future, a great way to test print styles is using Google Chrome's Developer's Tools.

When viewing page in Chrome, press F12. In the Emulation tab at the bottom, Click Media, check the box next to CSS media, and make sure the dropdown is set to print. Then you can view your page using your print stylesheet.

Comment: Adding a snippet of the code here so you can see how I added that.  It doesn't appear to have done anything.  I do appreciate your suggestion, maybe I've done something else goofey                     @media print {
body {background:white; 
     font-size:10pt; 
     margin:0 }
#sidebar { display:none }
#header, .nav-box, .noprint { display:none}

.drop-down-menu{display:none;}
#content{ margin-left:0; 
     float:none; 
     width:auto }
.demo .red { color:black; 
     font-weight:bold }
#content a { font-weight:bold; 
     color:#000066;

Comment: If you've added the code I provided, it should not appear. Have you saved your CSS to the server? Cleared your browser's cache? Checked if any caching plugins are running on the site?

Comment: When I look at your print style sheet in Chrome, the code you added appears there, and the menu is hidden for me.

Comment: As a side note, every CSS style should end in a semicolon. Things like this: .left { float: left } May not break on all browsers, but it's cleaner to do: .left { float: left; } and fits CSS standards.

Comment: It still shows up in Firefox and IE.  I did clear my cache.  I also just looked at it in Chrome and it is there as well.

Comment: On your styles, you have an extra semicolon. It should say .drop-down-menu{display:none !important;}, not .drop-down-menu{display:none; !important;}

Comment: There is another place that has .has-drop-down, I used that one as well and still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62624/discussion-between-joe-and-webby68).

Comment: You're using the wrong class. .drop-down-menu{display:none !important;}. I see you have .has-drop-down{display:none !important;} instead.